# searching across column value pairs -- SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i'm searching the database for matching values of a column pair.

say, the table T1 has these 3 columns:

```
(id, this, that)
```

and the query is

```
select id from T1 where 
    this = 'aValue' and that = 'bbb'
    OR this = 'CCCC' and that = 'DDD'
    OR this = 'EE' and that = 'EEE'.
```

is there a shortcut to this?

if i were searching on the values of one column only, say "this", it was easy:

```
    select id from T1 where this in ('aa', 'bbbb', 'cccc')
```

i'm using SQL Server.

TIA.

Comment: Nope, no good shortcuts -- you could concatonate the values together and use `in`, but you lose any advantages of indices at that point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `VALUES` clause to construct a table value, then inner join against this to get all matches:

```
SELECT id 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN (
   VALUES ('aValue', 'bbb'), ('CCCC', 'DDD'), ('EE', 'EEE') 
)  AS C(x,y) 
ON this = C.x AND that = C.y
```